# Getting data from API, need to filter results

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, restkit, foursquare

I'm working with data from a Foursquare API.

I want to get a list of coffee shops, and am getting that back correctly (I'm using RestKit)... but once I get that list, on my end I need to filter out any coffee shop that is a "Starbucks".

So right now I only know how to pull in all coffee shops, but I don't know how to parse that data once I have it before I serve it into the app table view so that there will be no Starbucks coffee shops listed.

Any ideas how I could do that?  Let me know if you need any of my code snippets posted that might help.  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Normal response type from the API would be:

```
"venue": [{
    "name": "ABC Coffee Shop", {
```

So I would need to take "name" and filter out any name that was `"Starbucks"`.

Comment: can you show the code when you obtain the response from the API?

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: I couldn't post the whole response because it was too much code, but this is the link to what a typical JSON response would look like via Foursquare: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime

Comment: @JulianOsorio Updated with an edit, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @ChrisWagner Updated with an edit, is that what you were looking for too?

Comment: please show us the code where you're obtaining data from API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If FourSquare doesn't let you apply a filter to the request, to filter on the name "Starbucks" then what I would do with this is the following.

I would start by deserializing the response into a JSON Object, which in this case will be a dictionary.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *responseDict = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:foursquareResponse options:0 error: &error];
NSArray *starbucks = nil;
if (!error) {
    NSArray *coffeeShops = responseDict[@"venue"];
    starbucks = [coffeeShops filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = 'Starbucks'"]];
} else {
    // handle the error
}

NSLog(@"Starbucks: %@", starbucks");
```

I didn't test this code but I think it should get you on your way.

Comment: Yeah sadly Foursquare doesn't let me apply the filter request, but your answer for how to filter makes sense to me so I'm gonna try it out.  This just goes in the viewDidLoad ya?

Comment: Could virtually go anywhere, I would think you'd want it to run when your web service call comes back.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question you should accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Question, since I stated that I'm using RestKit, do I need to use RKNSJSONSerialization or can I use just NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with RestKit, I'd suggest posting another question if you can't find information on it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JSON to me, you could just use the built in JSON parser, the `NSJSONSerialization` class. Here is a method I built that takes an `NSData` JSON parameter, deserializes it and returns a dictionary.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)deserialize: (NSData *)data {

    return [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error: nil] mutableCopy];
}
```

I don't know the structure of Foursquare's response inside out, so you might want to `NSLog()` the returned dictionary to see how you can now reference to it.

Comment: Sounds good, I've never used the built in JSON parser, so thanks for the heads up!  I'll give it a try and see if I can get it working.  Thanks!